# Floodfill implementetion

Tags: c++, 2d, flood-fill

I have a problem with my flood fill function:

```
void floodfill(int x, int y,Pixel old, Pixel new){

Pixel current = getPixel(x,y);

if(current.r == old.r && current.g == old.g && current.b == old.b){

    setPixel(x,y,new);

    floodfill(x+1,y,old,new);
    floodfill(x-1,y,old,new);
    floodfill(x,y+1,old,new);
    floodfill(x,y-1,old,new);
    floodfill(x+1,y+1,old,new);
    floodfill(x-1,y-1,old,new);
    floodfill(x+1,y+1,old,new);
    floodfill(x-1,y+1,old,new);
}
}
```

In struct 'Pixel' I have rgb values of the pixel. I am trying to fill a square and when I come to the border of the square (color changes from white to black, the border is at point x=200) the function is not changing to other pixels but just endlessly changing the x value to 198 and 199 (nevermind the y value). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're only filling if the current color is *equal to* the old color. Don't you want to fill only if the current color is *not equal to* the old color? P.S - `new` is a reserved keyword in C++ so you should not be trying to use it as a variable name.

Comment: What happens if `new` is equal to `old`?

Comment: ?? `new` is a keyword in C++; you can't use it for variable names.

Comment: Aardvarkk, the square is white inside and has a black borders. I set the old color to white, I want to set pixel and start recursion when the current color is white. When I get to the border of the square current changes to black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like setPixel isn't setting the colour of (x,y) to the "new". So, what's happening is the following sequence of recursive calls:

(199,y)->(200,y) [This stops because the border doesn't have the same colour as old]
       ->(198, y)->(199,y) [(199, y) is getting called because setPixel likely didn't change the colour of (199, y)]->...

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that you are filling `(x+1,y+1)` twice and missing `(x+1,y-1)`:

```
floodfill(x+1,y,old,new);
floodfill(x-1,y,old,new);
floodfill(x,y+1,old,new);
floodfill(x,y-1,old,new);
floodfill(x+1,y+1,old,new);
floodfill(x+1,y-1,old,new); //Missing this case
floodfill(x-1,y+1,old,new);
floodfill(x-1,y-1,old,new);
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistake but just after the first fill (x+1,y) my program loops.

Comment: Do you mean your program gets into an infinite loop or something else? I assume your square border has a complete solid outline including its corners filled with the old color?

Comment: Yes, infinite loop and the square border is solid black and corners are black too (square inside is white).

Comment: What sort of system are you on? Does `setPixel()` actually set the pixel's color or is there a buffering layer that may interfere with subsequent `getPixel()` calls?

Comment: I did a quick test and with the above fixes to the function and changing `new` to `newColor` it works fine (using a virtual pixel screen). This means the likely culprit is related to the `setPixel()/getPixel()` functions.